# Using Spring Security Annotations isFullyAuthenticated v/s hasRole

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

Being new to spring security annotations, I am not able to understand the real difference between the below two lines. Does it mean that hasRole implicitly checks for authentication?

```
-    @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('activateUser')")
+    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('activateUser')")

void activateUser(String username);
```

As per spring documentation,

```
isFullyAuthenticated()  Returns true if the user is not an anonymous or a remember-me user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that hasRole implicitly checks for authentication?

Not absolutely. It could be hasRole("ROLE_ANONYMOUS") which implies non authenticated users.
Note also that isFullyAuthenticted() is not the same as isAuthenticated() since the former required explicit authentication while the latter is more lax accepting remember-me authentiated users. In most cases though, hasRole is used with real roles which at least implies isAuthenticated().

So the difference is that the first line requires a user to be explicitly authenticated (not remember-me).